# Git server running on Windows 7

Tags: git

I would like to make some demos for my team that showcase interaction use cases between local and remote `Git` branches and simulate a multi developer teamwork environment.  To avoid creating new `GitHub` (which is what we use for remote) accounts, as well as to avoid cluttering the remote with demo dummies, I would prefer to mock a remote server on my `Windows 7` laptop and push there from my local branches, associated with different user accounts, that are all also on my laptop.  IOW, emulate a Git remote server on a Windows 7 laptop.  Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [local protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), and specify the file path as a remote. It should work regardless of operating system. Inside git bash, you can do

```
git init .
git remote add origin /path/to/remote/directory/on/localhost
# Add some stuff
git push origin master
```